# Get text written in Anchor tag without Id : javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string which has few content (URLs) I need to remove those or replace the with the tag text.

Input :

```
Entity Framework is an <a href="http://www.google.com">Object </a>/ Relational Mapper (O/RM) that helps you read and write data from and to a database. In this course, Mosh, teaches you the core concepts of Entity <a href="http://www.google.com">Framework</a>through a series of clear, concise and hands-on lectures.
```

output :

```
Entity Framework is an Object / Relational Mapper (O/RM) that helps you read and write data from and to a database. In this course, Mosh, teaches you the core concepts of Entity Framework through a series of clear, concise and hands-on lectures.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = 'Entity Framework is an <a href="http://www.google.com">Object </a>/ Relational Mapper (O/RM) that helps you read and write data from and to a database. In this course, Mosh, teaches you the core concepts of Entity <a href="http://www.google.com">Framework</a>through a series of clear, concise and hands-on lectures.'

var str1 = str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");

console.log(str1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`I need to remove those or replace the with the tag text.` In your example i see that you need just to remove the anchor tags and have only plain text.

From just your example, there is a simple solution.

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test")
test.innerHTML = test.innerText
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <a href="#">Some Link</a>
  Plain text
</div>
```

But if you need a more complex solution to select specific `links` and remove completely some of them and the other to be just text, that would require a more specific description from you.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can use `replace(..)` function with regx:

EX:

```
var text ='Entity Framework is an <a href="http://www.google.com">Object </a>/ Relational Mapper (O/RM) that helps you read and write data from and to a database. In this course, Mosh, teaches you the core concepts of Entity <a href="http://www.google.com">Framework</a>through a series of clear, concise and hands-on lectures.';

text.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
```